# io.crate.shade.org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 16 out of bounds for length 16

Tags: cratedb

using 4.0.0 version of cratedb

sample sql:

```sql
select * from table where col1 = 'exp1'  date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2022-02-14' 
right join dim.time where date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2022-02-14'
```

in this sql we know first part is empty data, and right join will case this error, but if I narrow down the date to '2020-01-01' AND '2022-02-14' it will work normal, also if I seperate two it works too. and if I delete the col1 filter it work too

[error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA3Zv.png)

[normal pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsS5j.png)

Answer (score 0):

This definitely looks like a bug and not a user error.
It might very well be that this is already fixed in a newer version of CrateDB. The current version is 4.7, while 4.0 is more than 2 years old.

Without the table schema (and most likely also dataset) it will not be easy to replicate this. If this can be replicated with a recent version, please report it as bug on Github -> https://github.com/crate/crate/issues